# How read in values from a column and use these values in an If statement inside a loop

Tags: excel, vba

My goal is to make a code that takes in the percent error from sheet 1 (column F) and then if the percent error if below 0.5% it takes the values from columns A:D that correspond with column f (for example if F6 had a percent error below 0.5% the program would copy A6:D6) and copies the cells and pastes them into sheet 2. Then this program needs to loop through all the values in column f and repeat this process.

I have had success with copying and pasting the cells I need using the code below without the If statement. However, I cannot seems to get a code that depends on the percent error.

'The start of the command button

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


Dim i As Long
Dim ii As Long
Dim i3 As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim sht2 As Worksheet
Dim Myrange As Range
Dim PerecntError As Integer



Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set sht1 = wb.Sheets("RawData")
Set sht2 = wb.Sheets("FilteredData")

'Find the last row (in column A) with data.
LastRow = sht1.Range("A:A").Find("*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
ii = 2
i = 3

'This is the beginning of the loop

For i = 1 To LastRow

If sht1.Range("F" & ii < 0.5) Then

        'First activity

        sht2.Range("A" & ii) = sht1.Range("A" & i).Value    
        sht2.Range("B" & ii) = sht1.Range("B" & i).Value  
        sht2.Range("C" & ii) = sht1.Range("C" & i).Value
        sht2.Range("D" & ii) = sht1.Range("D" & i).Value

        ii = ii + 1

      i = i + 1

End If

Next


End Sub
```

The error I am getting is that "Type mismatch" 
for this line: "If sht1.Range("F" & ii < 0.5) Then"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So I did change that, and I am no longer getting an error but it is no longer copying and pasting values. Is this because of the value I'm assigning it?

Comment: Why do you assign a value of 3 in `i = 3` then the very next executable line you assign a value of 1 in `For i = 1 To ...`?, then you `i = i + 1` when your `For i` statement would automatically increment this value anyway.

Comment: You're right that is also another mistake of mine. I have fixed that and have gotten the code to work. Thank you.

Comment: `i = i + 1` it's typically a good thing to never change the value of your loop counter inside the loop itself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If sht1.Range("F" & ii < 0.5) Then
```

should be

```
If sht1.Range("F" & ii) < 0.5 Then
```